# Can integration get the real value of $\pi$?

Tags: integration, geometry, pi

If you take the equation of a cicle $x^2+y^2=1$ and re write it as $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, why can't you use $\int_{-1}^{1}(\sqrt{1-x^2})dx$ to get the real value of $\pi$ even if you end up with more transcendental numbers?

Comment: That is how $\pi$ is sometimes defined. What do you mean by "even if you end up with more transcendental numbers"?

Comment: What do you mean by the "real value of $\pi$"?

Comment: @T.Bongers Probably, "not an approximation."

Comment: What I mean is even if you get a number like e in the answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The question is very unclear to say the least.

Comment: I was curious to know if that can be solved without estimating or rounding to be able to define pi.

Comment: Sure, you can define $\pi$ this way. To figure out the value, though, you'd have to use estimation - Riemann sums, assuming beginning calculus.

Comment: Yes, first semester.

Comment: @user3015600 I upvoted your question because, although not clearly stated, it shows a basic curiosity and original thought that many students seem to lack.  The answer you accepted is an excellent answer to your question.  There are many schemes to approximate value of your definite integral (which is $\pi$).  One of the best-known is Simpson's Rule, but that is just the tip of the iceberg.  People have written books on the subject, known as _quadrature_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is some confusion in the question. We can't calculate $\pi$ to infinite precision, because it's irrational. Therefore, anytime you see a list of digits of $\pi$, some kind of approximation has been used because if the list of digits ends, then it's not really $\pi$ but rather very close to it.

However, there are lots and lots of formulas that say $\pi$ is exactly equal to something else. Yours is one of them: $\pi = 2 \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx$. If you want to use this formula to calculate $\pi$, you are going to have to make some kind of approximation: either a Riemann sum, or a series expansion, or something. That's because you can never get $\pi$ with infinite precision, since, as I said before, it's irrational and so its decimal expansion is infinite but not periodic.

It's important to note that of the many many formulas for $\pi$, some are better suited for approximations than others. A pretty popular one is Machin's formula:

$$\frac{\pi}{4} = 4 \arctan\frac15 - \arctan \frac{1}{239}$$

The reason this formula is good is that the series expansion for $\arctan x$ converges pretty fast for small $x$. In fact, using the crudest approximation $\arctan x \approx x$, we get $\pi \approx 3.18$, not bad for such a simple calculation.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I should have worded the question to ask if that function could get pi to infinite precision.

Comment: @user3015600: You could, in principle, get $\pi$ with infinite precision. If you want any digit of the decimal expansion of $\pi$, there's a zillion formulas that you can use to get it. The problem is that we can never know all of them, not because math doesn't work, but simply because there's infinitely many of them and we don't have infinite time.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot: "arctan" is not an error. (Indeed, `$\arctan$` is supported in TeX. I personally often prefer it to $\tan^{-1}$ for pedagogic reasons.) Plaguing the Active Questions queue with trivial edits to dozens (hundreds?) of ancient posts is bad enough, but altering what is likely a purposeful notational choice of a contributor is so much worse. Please stop!

Comment: Downvote.  My opinion is that statements like "we can't calculate $\pi$ to infinite precision" are highly misleading.  What does it mean to calculate a number to infinite precision?  Can we calculate $1/7$ to infinite precision?  What about the number whose $n$th digit is a $1$ if $n$ is prime, and $0$ otherwise?  What about $\sqrt{2}$?  Does this concept have any precise meaning?